# Create Powershell env variables using built in System variables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-powershell

I have a Powershell script that will make a GET request to SonarQube's REST API to check if the Quality Gate passes or fails. If the Quality Gate fails, the pipeline will fail. I am able to make this work when only looking at the master branch however, I am trying to look at all branches and pull requests.

My pipeline Powershell script:

```
  - job:
  
    pool:
      name: 'POEM-GBT-Agent'

    variables:
    - group: SonarQube

    displayName: 'SonarQube API'
    
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        $token = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$(SONARQUBE_API_TOKEN)" + ":")
        $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($token)
        
        $basicAuth = [string]::Format("Basic {0}", $base64)
        $headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuth }

        if ($(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)) {
           $param = "pullRequest=$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
        }
        else {
          $param = "branch=$env:$BRANCH_NAME"
        }
        
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://sonarqube.tjx.com/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$(sonarProjectKey)"&"$param -Headers $headers
        $result | ConvertTo-Json | Write-Host
        
        if ($result.projectStatus.status -ne "OK") {
          Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Quality Gate Failed"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed]"
        }

        env:
          BRANCH_NAME: replace('$(Build.SourceBranch)', 'refs/heads/', '')
```

This results in an error saying:

```
+   $param = "branch=$env:$BRANCH_NAME"
+                    ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name 
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

After receiving this error I changed my conditional statement to:

```
        if ($(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)) {
           $param = "pullRequest=$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
        }
        else {
          $param = "branch=${env}:$BRANCH_NAME"
        }
```

After changing my conditional I get this error:

```
System.PullRequest.PullRequestId : The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' 
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\GBT\agent\Workspace\_temp\0a756446-474a-4d58-94ff-ad25e38c3c7a.ps1:9 
char:7
+ if ($(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)) {
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.PullRequest.PullRequestI 
   d:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am trying to set `$param` to `pullRequest=1234` if the Git PR is affected, otherwise, I want to set `$param` to something like `branch=feature/my-branch-name`.

Comment: You may already know this but the Sonarqube extension has this implemented as a task already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here. I'll delve into each below.

---

### The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' is not recognized

Under your job `step`, define some environment variables. I have limited experience with Azure DevOps (will reference as ADO from here on) but you will need two under your `powershell` environment variable definitions (you already have `BRANCH_NAME` but I will include it below):

```yaml
- job:
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      YOUR
      CODE
      HERE

    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: replace('$(Build.SourceBranch)', 'refs/heads/', '')
      PULL_REQUEST_ID: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

You need to define `PULL_REQUEST_ID` as an env var because your rendered PowerShell script won't render `$()` as an inserted value from ADO. This is likely by design as `$()` is syntax used in other programming languages, [including PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--). This is the crux of your issue where `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` can't be found as a command; PowerShell literally tries to use that as a program name which it can't find.

Within your script, you can then reference the pull request ID with:

```
$env:PULL_REQUEST_ID
```

---

### Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character

The issue is distinct from the issue above, but the solution is the same. Just reference the environment variable as:

```
$env:BRANCH_NAME
```

You don't need the extra `$`, as this just confuses the parser.

Now, you're not asking for this, but if you needed a conditional environment variable name (e.g. the name of the environment variable is sourced from some other ADO variable), you need to use a different syntax to access the environment variable, as the `$` confuses the parser when accessed via the `$env:` syntax. **Read on if you are curious about this**.

---

### If you did need to access an environment variable whose name is conditional

PowerShell doesn't allow special characters in variable names without specifying the variable name as a string. The notable exceptions are `_` (no special meaning) and `:`, the latter of which is used as a separator for variables defined *within a `PSDrive`*. Environment variables are accessible via the `Environment` provider, which is accessed under the `Env` `PSDrive`. You can see this by running `Get-PSDrive`, there is an `Environment` provider exposed under the `Env` drive.

You can reference `PSProvider` variables in a few ways, the most common way is `$drive:path` (the variable name is technically considered a path node under the provider). So to reference the `UserProfile` variable, you can use:

```
$env:UserProfile # ====> Returns the path to your user profile directory
```

The problem with your code is you have the following:

```
$env:$VariableName
```

In this case the intent is to get an environment variable value whose name is based on another variable's value, but this confuses the parser for this syntax, as `$` is now being translated as a literal portion of the variable name, which is invalid. Normally you would use the `${}` syntax to avoid this... but you can't here, because the confused portion should be rendered as part of that same variable. In this case, you need to use an alternative approach to access the environment variable, go through the provider directly.

To use `UserProfile` as an example again:

```
$envVarName = 'UserProfile'
$envVarValue = (Get-ChildItem Env:/$envVarName).Value
```

This is the other way to get a value from a `PSProvider`; traverse its contents as a drive. This works somewhat like a filesystem, though `Get-ChildItem` will return different properties for different provider types than the `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` objects you may be used to from the `Filesystem` provider. It's a bit cumbersome, but luckily it's not a scenario one often needs to account for.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, I appreciate it! I changed my `$param` to `$param = 'pullRequest"&"branch=$(( Get-ChildItem Env:/$BRANCH_NAME ).Value)'` and that works exactly as I'd like it to. Having some issues with `$env:PULL_REQUEST_ID` as it's saying : `{"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact 
your administrator"}]}` which makes me think I'm listening for the PR incorrectly

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` is only initialized if "the build ran because of a [Git PR affected by a branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies#build-validation)".

Comment: If you're having further issues with this behavior, I would suggest a new question as this one is focused on resolving PowerShell syntax errors, but you are now having a new issue related to the execution context of your ADO pipeline.